# What is shorter Java code equivalent to Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") in VB.Net?

Tags: java, vb.net, date, migration, date-formatting

I'm converting a VB.Net program to Java and I have to convert following line

```
Dim s = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I have written following Java code

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String s = sdf.format(d);
```

that I can write on one line

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```

What is the **shorter** code in Java that works in Java 6 and greater ?

Is there some Java codes that generates date formatted string in calling a  method of Date object (example: `Date.format("yyyy-MM-dd")`) ?

Comment: A date format object is expensive to create. This way you have a chance to re-use it. But take care - it's not thread-safe. Maybe this answers the question why there is no shorter alternative.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Don’t strive for short code. Strive for clearly readable code instead. Sometimes they will happen to be the same, sometimes the shorter code is less readable.

Comment: `String s = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`, that is not vb...

Comment: yes it is not VB. I will correct that.

Answer (score 2):

### What is the shorter code in Java that works in Java 6 and greater ?

I’d like to answer the “Java 6 and greater” part: The code in deHaar’s answer does. My version would be either

```
    String now = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString();
```

or

```
    DateTimeFormatter customFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd");
    String now = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(customFormatter);
```

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) java.time, the modern API, comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: I want to vote up but I don't have sufficient reputations ! Thanks for your answer for any Java version.

Answer (score 1):

From Java 8 on, there is `java.time` with several useful classes.

If you may / can use Java 8 or higher, then you can do the following:

```
String now = LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

which will output `2018-12-05` today in my time zone (may differ in yours).

You just need to

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

in order to make it work.
You can as well apply custom formattings with

```
DateTimeFormatter customFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
String now = LocalDate.now().format(customFormatter);
```

Comment: For the first snippet you may alternatively use just `LocalDate.now().toString()`. I recommend giving explicit time zone to `now`, even if you just do `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. It more clearly states what you expect to get.

Comment: I want to vote up but I don't have sufficient reputations ! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can accept it as the correct answer... No problem if you cannot upvote it, I remember having been in that situation some months ago ;-)

Comment: I have accepted it but it is refused until I have 15 reputations ! Sorry

Comment: Again no problem, you can upvote and/or accept the answers given by @OleV.V. and me later when you have enough reputation.